# Removed rvm but gem env still says my INSTALLATION DIRECTORY is .rvm/gems which doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am trying to remove RVM from my desktop (which used ruby 1.9), so I can use vanilla ruby 2.3, which works on my formatted laptop. So I did

```
rvm implode
```

That got rid of the `~/.rvm` dir and I soon got `ruby --version` to say it uses 2.3.1 etc. However when I do `gem env`, I still get:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2015-06-17 patchlevel 551) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/share/jruby/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/foo/.gem/specs
```

Note that the `/home/foo/.gem/` directory doesn't exist any more! How can I fix `gem env`? I am using Fedora 23 (soon 24) and I want to reset it to the system's default.

I tried a bunch of things (like reinstalling rubygems) with no luck.

Comment: Does this persist after you create a new shell? RVM is loaded in as a series of shell extensions and can't easily uninstall itself from existing sessions. In other words, "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: I've started a new terminal every time, but I haven't rebooted my OS.

Comment: If running `rvm` produces an invalid command then your `gem env` should be back to normal. Until then either it's lingering around somehow or hasn't been fully removed.